# Define parameterized policy in OpenAM

Tags: openam

We're looking into using OpenAM to handle security for a web app that we've created.  I'm wondering about the/a proper way to set up policies that can be parameterized by value.  Specifically, we sell items by county.  Each user purchases either a few counties or all counties.  I know that we could create a role/group/realm for every county in the US, and assign users to the appropriate roles/groups/realms.  But that's a lot of things to manage when we'll never have a user buy more than five.  Is there a way I can define a rule or policy to say "allow if the resource's county is in the user's list of counties"?

It seems like this should be possible.  But I've been looking through OpenAM documentation, and I can't see a place where it says how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible by implementing a custom Policy Condition. In your condition you could check the accessed URL (the policy evaluation mode needs to be self though) and you should have also access to the user's session ID, which should allow you to determine if the given user has the necessary privileges to access the given resource.

The documentation is a little bit sparse about this, but should help in general:
http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index.html#chap-policy-spi